# View debugging of UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, uicollectionview

Is there a way to debug UI of custom `UICollectionViewCell` in XCode? All I can see in the view debugging of the `UICollectionView` is the cell being displayed as one solid UIView without any subviews, like this:

[image: View debugging]

I would like to see all the subviews so I could easily debug `UILabel` frames and so on. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.. finally figured out this occurs when you add subviews directly to `UICollectionViewCell` instead of adding subviews to it's `contentView`.

**Example:**

This codes shows properly in the view debugger:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var fillView: UIView? {
        didSet {
            guard oldValue != fillView else {return}

            oldValue?.removeFromSuperview()

            if let fillView = fillView {
                contentView.addSubview(fillView)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This **does not** show properly in the view debugger:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var fillView: UIView? {
        didSet {
            guard oldValue != fillView else {return}

            oldValue?.removeFromSuperview()

            if let fillView = fillView {
                // Note: not adding to `contentView`
                addSubview(fillView)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend the Tool of [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/),it's a very powerful debugger tool for UI

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try :)